# apigee geoqueries return 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: apigee

I have my defined entity with location property set, but when I use geoqueries, it doesn't work. Tried with both JavaScript SDK and cURL. With cURL, it returned 400 BAD REQUEST.

Here's one of the entity:

```
{
address : 132 Canal St, Boston, MA 02114
created : 1405138421997
location :
    latitude : -71.06065690000003
    longitude : 42.36471450000001
metadata :
path : /bars/e889e9ee-097a-11e4-98ef-f94f76c7327e
modified : 1405390673164
name : Sports Grill Boston
region : Charlestown
type : bars
uuid : e889e9ee-097a-11e4-98ef-f94f76c7327e
website : http://www.sportsgrilleboston.com/
}
```

And here's the cURL command:
curl -v -X GET "https://api.usergrid.com/my-org/my-app/bars?access_token=token&ql=location within 16000 of 42.358431,-71.059773"

And here's the returns:

```
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f8bab003c00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to api.usergrid.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 54.209.30.241...
* Connected to api.usergrid.com (54.209.30.241) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.0 connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate: api.usergrid.com
* Server certificate: Thawte SSL CA
* Server certificate: thawte Primary Root CA
* Server certificate: Thawte Premium Server CA
> GET /my-org/my-app/bars?access_token=token&ql=location within 16000 of 42.358431,-71.059773 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: api.usergrid.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: Close
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Can you try adding a space between the lon and lat?

Comment: Yes, I did. Actually I had space originally. No luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - you need to URL encode the request:

```
curl -v -X GET "https://api.usergrid.com/my-org/my-app/bars?access_token=token&ql=location%20within%2016000%20of%2042.358431,%20-71.059773"
```